# Options for semi-permanent memory in a low-energy setting

Tags: low-power, memory, mram

(Hopefully this will be broad enough to be on-topic.)

I'm looking for options to store several megabytes of data over the period of a few weeks in a coin-cell powered application. The data doesn't need to survive a power outage (dead battery, etc.), but I do expect to perform several hundred reads and writes over the life of a single battery.

What technology type would be the most power efficient? The flash options I'm looking at (such as the [m24px80](https://www.micron.com/~/media/Documents/Products/Data%20Sheet/NOR%20Flash/Serial%20NOR/M25PX/M25PX_80.pdf)) have fairly substantial current draw on write (15mA @ 3V). What other options are there?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact technology, but a PC BIOS settings are stored in volatile memory ("CMOS") and a coin cell will keep it alive, as well as the TOY clock running for quite a while.

Comment: Oops - your comment made me realize I was missing a piece of the use case. The issue isn't just storage, it's also being able to read and write to it, several hundred times.

Comment: Serial EEPROM would only use 2mA, but you'd be looking at 24 * 1Mb or 12 * 2Mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a low-power Static RAM (SRAM). You need to look at devices that are specified for low-power or "ultra low-power". For long battery life, low standby power can be especially important.

Here is an example from Cypress: [CY62167DV30](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/100/CY62167DV30_38-05328-319217.pdf) which lists a typical standby current of 2.5µA

A supervisory circuit for controlling SRAM power and chip-enable is often also used. One example is the [TPS3613-01 from TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvs340d/slvs340d.pdf)

---

Regarding the Micron M25PX80 NOR Serial Flash device you referenced: For only a few hundred reads and writes over the life of the battery, the 15mA write current may not be such a big concern if you can take advantage of the "Deep power-down" mode when the device is idle. Specifications for that mode indicate a maximum current of 10µA (Device Grade 6).

Answer (score 1):

Some of TI's MSP430 microcontrollers provide persistent storage in [FRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectric_RAM), which has some very interesting characteristics:

- It's non-volatile - no power is required for data retention.
- Fast read and write times (TI claims 50 ns)
- High endurance (TI, again, claims 10^15 cycles)

(The numbers I'm quoting are from [TI's FRAM FAQ](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slat151/slat151.pdf).)

Of course, this is only useful to you if the MSP430 is an option — it's not available as a standalone part at this time.

Comment: Nice find, however TI lists "Up to 128 KB FRAM" so may not have sufficient capacity for the OP's requirement of "several megabytes".

Answer (score 0):

An SRAM might do it. Microchips 23A1024 for instance, it draws 3mA at READ at 5.5V 20MHz, they can be driven by voltages down to 1.7V depending on model. Unfortunately they are quite small, only 1Mbit.

Answer (score 0):

Another option : MRAM : Nonvolatile magnetoresistive memory.
http://www.everspin.com/

High density chips are available (>1MB)

As the supply current is quite high, you would have to power-off the chip between accesses.

Comment: Good to know about, but the current requirements for a write operation are an order of magnitude higher than flash. Not gonna work for me.